# Perl regex: string literal containing metacharacters as variable for match expression

Tags: regex, perl

I need to define a string literal as a variable which will be later used as a match expression.

I want my variable **$regex_op** to match the string **alt_id: ID:** as well as the string **id: ID:**.

```
my $regex_op = "(id|alt_id):\sID:";
my $searchword = "4";
```

Later on, I'm joining the variables in a regular expression:

```
/^($regex_op)($searchword)/m
```

Unfortunately, the whitespace wildcard **\s** is an *"Unrecognized escape \s passed through"*.
The problem apparently consists in the string literal containing backslashes (which are needed as part of the regex later on!).

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For regexes, use regex quotes `qr//`. This ensures the correct parsing rules for regexes are used, not those for double quoted strings:

```
my $regex_op   = qr/(?:id|alt_id):\sID:/;  # I think that group should be non-capturing
my $searchword = 4;
/^$regex_op($searchword)/m;  # no need to group $regex_op; unless you want to capture
```

In a double quoted string, if a backslash is followed by a character that is not a known escape, then that character is left as is, but the backslash removed:

```
"\s" eq "s"
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I didn't know that it is possible to define regexp as variables and the non-capturing of groups is quite helpful, too. Is it necessary to group $searchword in the regex when it's a string?

Comment: `id` on its own also matches `alt_id`, so without any sort of anchor, adding it in the alternation is not needed, unless it is captured and handled as a different value. I.e. either `(id|alt_id)` and use the value, or just `id`.

Comment: But I need to find either **id** or **alt_id** at the beginning of a line. Is there a more elegant way to write the regex, as in "match either **alt_** or nothing before **id**"?

Comment: One could do `qr/(?:alt_)?id:\sID/`, but I think the explicit alternation `alt_id|id` is more elegant.

Comment: @atreju If you want the beginning of line, but don't need to capture, `^(?:id|alt_id)` would be what you need. Note the use of `^` to denote beginning of line anchor.